# MVVM ViewModel constructor instantiated several times

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, constructor, caliburn.micro

would somebody mind helping me with a WPF MVVM understanding problem? 
I built a MVVM project with caliburn.micro as MVVM framework. Please bear with me as this is the first time I created this kind of project. The grid should show up a kind of a home screen (HomeViewModel). 
Therefore a Binding on it has been added to the content control.
Can someone assist and tell me why the constructor of my HomeViewModel is instantiated 3 times?
On the other hand I would be fine if someone could explain how to implement methods to the ViewModels? All of them, including logging are executed three times.

```
<Window [...]>
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ShellViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:HomeViewModel}">
            <local:HomeView DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Binding FallbackValue="{x:Null}"
                     Mode="OneWay"
                     Path="viewModels:HomeViewItem"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

I implemented a SimpleContainer as per the caliburn.micro documentation at my bootstrapper:

```
    public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private SimpleContainer _container;

    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _container = new SimpleContainer();

        _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();

        // Registering ViewModels
        GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.IsClass)
            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
            .Where(type => !(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type.Namespace)) && type.Namespace.EndsWith("ViewModels"))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(viewModelType => _container.RegisterSingleton(
                viewModelType, viewModelType.ToString(), viewModelType));

        // Registering Views
        GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.IsClass)
            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("View"))
            .Where(type => !(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type.Namespace)) && type.Namespace.EndsWith("Views"))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(viewModelType => _container.RegisterSingleton(
                viewModelType, viewModelType.ToString(), viewModelType));

    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.BuildUp(instance);
    }
```

My HomeViewModel is implemented like this:

```
    public class HomeViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>
    {
        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello from HomeVM");
        }
    }
```

And my ShellViewModel like this:

```
    public class ShellViewModel : Screen
{
    private IScreen _homeViewItem;

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        CreateSourceItem();
    }


    public IScreen HomeViewItem
    {
    get => _homeViewItem;
    set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _homeViewItem))
                return;
            _homeViewItem = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => HomeViewItem);
        }
    }

    private void CreateSourceItem() 
    {
        HomeViewItem = new HomeViewModel();
    }
}
```

When the application starts there are 3 entries for HomeViewModel implementation in debug output:

```
Hello from HomeVM
Hello from HomeVM
Hello from HomeVM
```

If the constructor is called several times, the Singleton DI within the container should return the existing instance, shouldn't it? 
By the way: The StartupUri has been removed from app.xaml.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you set the DataContext in XAML that will create an instance. CreateSourceItem method creates an instance and the DI container. 1+1+1=3 q.e.d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This markup calls ShellViewModel's constructor

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ShellViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

which calls HomeViewModel's constructor via

```
public ShellViewModel()
{
    CreateSourceItem();
}
private void CreateSourceItem() 
{
    HomeViewItem = new HomeViewModel();
}
```

And 2 more calls here

```csharp
GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.IsClass)
            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
            .Where(type => !(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type.Namespace)) && type.Namespace.EndsWith("ViewModels"))
            .ToList() // <= !!! look here in debugger, what ToList() returns.
            // Here foreach loop calls constructor ShellViewModel()
            // which calls HomeViewModel() via CreateSourceItem() again
            // then the loop calls constructor of HomeViewModel() separately.
            .ForEach(viewModelType => _container.RegisterSingleton(
                viewModelType, viewModelType.ToString(), viewModelType));
```

**Total:** 3 times. All correct.

*Singleton is dangerous.*

Comment: Thanks in advance! Is there a best practise way to combine that?

Comment: @AtzeBK you should select the only approach for initializing the instances. Manual, or Singleton implementation. That's it.